# Spark error: missing parameter type in map()

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-graphx

I am trying to learn Spark GraphX on Windows 10 by replicating the [code here](http://sparktutorials.net/analyzing-flight-data:-a-gentle-introduction-to-graphx-in-spark). The code is developed using an older version of Spark and I'm not able to find a solution to create a vertex. The following is the code

```
import scala.util.MurmurHash
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

val path = "F:/Soft/spark/2008.csv"
val df_1 = spark.read.option("header", true).csv(path)

val flightsFromTo = df_1.select($"Origin",$"Dest")
val airportCodes = df_1.select($"Origin", $"Dest").flatMap(x => Iterable(x(0).toString, x(1).toString))

// error caused by the following line
val airportVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = airportCodes.distinct().map(x => (MurmurHash.stringHash(x), x))
```

The following is the error message:

```
<console>:57: error: missing parameter type
       val airportVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = airportCodes.distinct().map(x => (MurmurHash.stringHash(x), x))
                                                                                  ^
```

I think the syntax is obsolete and I tried to find the latest syntax on [official documents](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html) but it was of no help. The data set can be downloaded from [here](http://stat-computing.org/dataexpo/2009/2008.csv.bz2).

**UPDATE:**

Basically, I'm trying to create a Vertex and Edge, to finally create a graph as shown in the [tutorial](http://sparktutorials.net/analyzing-flight-data:-a-gentle-introduction-to-graphx-in-spark). I'm also new to the Map-Reduce paradigm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following lines of code worked for me.

```
// imported latest library - works without this too, just gives a warning
import scala.util.hashing.MurmurHash3

// datasets are set to rdd - this is the cause of the error
val flightsFromTo = df_1.select($"Origin",$"Dest").rdd
val airportCodes = df_1.select($"Origin", $"Dest").flatMap(x => Iterable(x(0).toString, x(1).toString)).rdd

val airportVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = airportCodes.distinct().map(x => (MurmurHash3.stringHash(x), x))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:
        val airportVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] =        airportCodes.distinct().map(x => (MurmurHash.stringHash(x(0)), x(1)))

Comment: It still gives the same error: `<console>:37: error: missing parameter type
       val airportVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = airportCodes.distinct().map(x => (MurmurHash.stringHash(x(0)), x(1)))`

Answer (score 1):

// In order to apply map(), just try to convert the variable to RDD.

val airportVertices: RDD[(VertexId, String)] = airportCodes.rdd.distinct().map(x => (MurmurHash3.stringHash(x), x))